# Finding threshold frequency of a metal

Tags: energy

> Find threshold frequency, in $\mathrm{Hz}$, of a metal if it emits an electron with kinetic energy of $2.74 \times 10^{-19}~\mathrm{J}$ when illuminated with light with frequency of $1.49 \times 10^{15}~\mathrm{Hz}$.

I am not sure what to do with this.

Comment: Welcome to this site. Note that this site is not for homework help. For [tag:homework] questions, please include your attempt, or else your question might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: What have you tried?  Take a shot at it anyway ;)  You'll be much more likely to get help when people see you've put some effort into it.